# I update my xampp and i face this errors Notice: Undefined variable: session in

Tags: xampp, localhost

I update my xampp and i face this errors Notice: Undefined variable: session in
I try to php.ini but no solution i have more than 30 scipts in my localhost and i want to ignore this errors.
How can i do this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: But i want to include code in php.ini so i not have to declare all time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this at the end of your php.ini

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

Make that is right php.ini

Comment: Thanks Man I got my answer